# Comparing value with previous row in pandas DataFrame and colour them with yellow and green

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-formatting, pandas-styles

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': [1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1],
                   'Value2': [3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Value3': [3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Value1  Value2  Value3
0       1       3       3
1       3       1       2
2       3       2       4
3       1       3       6
4       2       2       7
5       3       5       5
6       2       6       4
7       5       1       3
8       6       2       2
9       1       3       1
```

I have the following pandas DataFrame and I want to create another column that compares the previous row of `Value1` to see if the value of the row is greater than that of the previous row. It should come out like the following:

```
   Value1  match
0       1  False
1       3  False
2       3   True
3       1  False
4       2  False
5       3   True
6       2  False
7       5  False
8       6   True
9       1   True
```

This is the solution I have got for 1 column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': [1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1]})

df['match'] = df['Value1'].gt(df['Value1'].shift(-1, fill_value=-1))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Value1  match
0       1  False
1       3  False
2       3   True
3       1  False
4       2  False
5       3   True
6       2  False
7       5  False
8       6   True
9       1   True
```

But I need the same cell to be coloured, also I want to apply this to multiple columns. As shown below:

[image]

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: In the col1 I want my cells to be colored based on the comparison.
like index 0 has 1 and index 1 has 1 and 3 value respectively, if we compare 1 and 3, 1 is small and has to be marked yellow and 3 as green. similarly, next values 3 and 3 are the same they can be marked green as no increase and decrease are there.

Comment: I think the question is which are yellow and which are green? "apply this to multiple columns" how? Do you mean test multiple columns and colour them based on separate values or apply the colouring to the entire row _across_ columns?

Comment: I want to apply colouring to the entire row across the columns

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would mock up an example in excel or some similar program to _show_ what your expected colouring should be. Especially in the more complicated case of multiple columns because the approach differs for 1 vs many.

Comment: @HenryEcker - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jtGG.png

Comment: I've mostly got my answer together. My only question is why is `3` in the first row green for row 0? It's not increased from the previous value as there is no previous value.

Comment: First value of a column will be compared to second value, lowest value will be yellow and higher value will be green. In the next iteration second value will be compared to third value to label the third value ( either green or yellow ).